# Strategy to unprovision old applicationtype versions in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to set some sort of configuration on the cluster to remove service fabric application type versions? Like only keep the last 5 versions or something?

For example i have CI/CD deploying new versions of a service fabric app to our cluster, it leaves a bunch of application version types in the cluster. Is there a way to automatically unprovision them over time or only keep a certain number of versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options that cross  my mind -

- Specify **UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade = $true** when you execute Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1. This parameter indicates whether to unregister any unused application versions that exist after an upgrade is finished.
- Add custom script into your release defintion, deployment script or whereever you want that will resolve all the deployed app types and unprovision those ones that you think are obsolete. Here is the command that 
  you will need to use - [Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/unregister-servicefabricapplicationtype?view=azureservicefabricps). Here is some example of the script that unregisters all the app types except running ones -

  ```
  #resolve all app types
  $appTypes = Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType
  foreach($appType in $appTypes)
  {
     #try to find the match with any of installed applications
     $match = Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationTypeName $appType.ApplicationTypeName | Where-Object {$_.ApplicationTypeVersion -eq $appType.ApplicationTypeVersion}
     if(!$match)
     {
         Write-Host "Deleting $($appType.ApplicationTypeName) $($appType.ApplicationTypeVersion)"
         Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName $appType.ApplicationTypeName -ApplicationTypeVersion $appType.ApplicationTypeVersion -Force -Confirm
     }    
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `CleanupUnusedApplicationTypes` to `true` in the `Management` section of cluster settings to enable automatic cleanup. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings#management):

> This configuration if enabled, allows to automatically unregister unused application type versions skipping the latest three unused versions, thereby trimming the disk space occupied by image store. The automatic cleanup will be triggered at the end of successful provision for that specific app type and also runs periodically once a day for all the application types. Number of unused versions to skip is configurable using parameter "MaxUnusedAppTypeVersionsToKeep".

I believe this requires at least Service Fabric 6.5.

Comment: Should be the Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on Kiyrl's answer keeping the currently deployed version + n history'

```
#resolve all app types
$appTypes = Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType
$deployedAppArray = @()
foreach($appType in $appTypes){    
    #try to find the match with any of installed applications
    $match = Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationTypeName $appType.ApplicationTypeName | Where-Object {$_.ApplicationTypeVersion -eq $appType.ApplicationTypeVersion}
    if(!$match)
    {
        $oldApp = new-object psobject -property @{
            ApplicationTypeName = $appType.ApplicationTypeName
            ApplicationTypeVersion  = $appType.ApplicationTypeVersion 
        }
        $deployedAppArray += $oldApp
    }    
}

$countToKeep = 2 # keeps this many in addition + currently deployed
$uniqueAppTypes = $deployedAppArray | Group-Object "ApplicationTypeName" | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt $countToKeep } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($appType in $uniqueAppTypes){ 
    $versionsToRemove = $deployedAppArray | Where-Object {$_.ApplicationTypeName -eq $appType}
    $toRemoveCount =  $versionsToRemove.Length - $countToKeep
    $versionsToRemove = $versionsToRemove | Select-Object -First $toRemoveCount

    foreach($appToRemove in $versionsToRemove){
        Write-Host "Removing $($appToRemove.ApplicationTypeName) $($appToRemove.ApplicationTypeVersion)"
        Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName $appToRemove.ApplicationTypeName -ApplicationTypeVersion $appToRemove.ApplicationTypeVersion -Force
    }
}
```